# uibutton selector send string as parameter

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I need to send a string as parameter in `UIButton` selector. Taking global string won't work for me. Button is of custom type. I tried :

```
btn.titleLabel.text = str;
```

And accessed it in selector, but received **nil**.

Comment: what is your selector name ??

Comment: Really !! And how to pass parameter in [button addTarget] ?

Comment: If you add target in button then below given answer will help you ..

Comment: Only you write in add targe like this: @selector(ShowImage:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get it like this

```
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTap:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)buttonTap:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *b = (UIButton*)sender;
     NSLog(@"%@",b.titleLabel.text);
}
```